# hibernate InstantiationException after upgrading from Spring Boot 2.7.12 to 3.1.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

Since the upgrade of the spring boot version to 3.1.0 and the consequent replacement of javax with jakarta, I am unable to compile integration tests (and the problem will occur when the application is running) due to the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to locate constructor for embeddable : com.example.nccn.aggregator.db.foo.FooEntityId
```

`Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Unable to locate constructor for embeddable : com.example.nccn.aggregator.db.foo.FooEntityId`

The entity looks like this:

```
@Embeddable
class FooEntityId(
    @Column(name = "id")
    var id: Long,
) : Serializable
```

and its a part of a:

```
@Embeddable
class FooFooEntityId(
    @Embedded
    var fooEntityId: FooEntityId,

[...]
) : Serializable
```

which is used in:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo_table", schema = "example")
data class ExampleEntity(
    @EmbeddedId
    var id: FooFooEntityId? = null,
[...]
)
```

For all listed and other defined entities, information appears at the beginning, which was not there before - `No default (no-argument) constructor for class: com.example.nccn.aggregator.db.foo.FooEntityId (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)`.

Current setup:
Spring Boot 3.1.0
Java 17
Kotlin 1.7.0
Also, I use plugins:
Kotlin:
-all-open
-spring
-no-args
-jpa
The plugins assure me, among other things, that no-argument constructors should be generated, which are needed by hibernate.
I checked the bytecode and decompiled it - there are no-argument constructors.

Comment: Have you checked the bytecode of generated classes to ensure that no-arg constructor is indeed there?

Comment: I checked the bytecode and decompiled it - there are no-argument constructors.

Comment: That's a good sign, means the plugins are working fine. What version of Hibernate do you use?

Comment: Hibernate 6.1.7  as is a dependency of a spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Comment: I run into the same problem upgrading to Spring Boot 3.1.4 as well. Have similar versions of Kotlin and Java. Did you find out why in the end @enccne